# Batch move files named in a text file to directories provided by text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to move some files named in one text file to directories named in another different text file. Using Batch commands.

What I've tried.

```
@echo off 
echo.
REM check if file is there
if exist K:\file_sync_diff\FileNameList.txt goto Label 1
REM display error
echo Can not find the File Name List
echo.
echo.
Pause
goto :eof

:Label 1
REM display that the file in the last check was found
echo found FileNameList.txt
REM check if file is there
if exist K:\file_sync_diff\FileDumpText.txt goto Label 2
REM display error
echo Can not find File Dump Text File
echo.
echo.
Pause
goto :eof

:Label 2
REM display that the file in the last check was found
echo found FileDumpText.txt
REM check if file is there
if exist K:\file_sync_diff\DirectoryNames.txt goto Label 3
REM display error
echo Can not find Directory Names Text File
echo.
echo.
Pause
goto :eof

:Label 3
REM display that the file in the last check was found
echo found DirectoryNames.txt
REM for loop to filter through every line in a file
echo.
for /f %%i in (K:\file_sync_diff\FileNameList.txt) do call :Sub %%i
goto Label 4
goto :eof

:Label 4
REM display message of the file being moved
echo.
echo Moving %1
REM copy the file just made to a directory with a name supplied in a text file 
for /f %%i in (K:\file_sync_diff\DirectoryNames.txt) do call :Sub 2 %%i
echo.
goto :eof

:Sub
echo Writing %1
REM copy the contents of FileDumpText.txt to the file that was passed in the last method
type K:\file_sync_diff\FileDumpText.txt >>  %1.txt
goto :eof

:Sub 2
REM moves the file to the directory supplied by label 4.
move /y %1.txt %1
echo.
goto :eof
```

Contents of `FileNameList.txt`

```
red 
orange
purple
```

Contents of `DirectoryNames.txt`

```
K:\file_sync_diff\cat
K:\file_sync_diff\dog
K:\file_sync_diff\333
```

Not that it matters but the contents of `FileDumpText.txt`
Test text to be passed to the file

```
more text 1
more text 2
more text 3
```

The directories do exist in the `K:\file_sync_diff` folder.

Thank you for your help.

The end result should be the following
directory cat with red.txt inside with all of the contents of FileDumpText.txt inside it
directory dog with orange.txt inside with all of the contents of FileDumpText.txt inside it
directory 333 with purple.txt inside with all of the contents of FileDumpText.txt inside it

Comment: It would make the problem much easier to solve if you removed all of the extraneous code and simplified it to a for loop that simply tried to read the file list and echoed the file name, and then built up from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was successful using the following code, but with one issue. I get a ".txt" file now. This is caused by a return charter in the FileNameList.txt file but if their is no return after the last file name in the FileNameList.txt then that file doesn't get copied. 
So I just need a line of code to delete ".txt" and not any other file with an actual name.txt Any help with that would be nice.

My current Code

```
@echo off 
echo.
REM check if file is there
if exist F:\file_sync_diff\FileNameList.txt goto Label 1
REM display error
echo Can not find the File Name List
echo.
echo.
Pause
goto :eof

:Label 1
REM display that the file in the last check was found
echo found FileNameList.txt
REM check if file is there
if exist F:\file_sync_diff\FileDumpText.txt goto Label 2
REM display error
echo Can not find File Dump Text File
echo.
echo.
Pause
goto :eof

:Label 2
REM display that the file in the last check was found
echo found FileDumpText.txt
REM check if file is there
if exist F:\file_sync_diff\DirectoryNames.txt goto Label 3
REM display error
echo Can not find Directory Names Text File
echo.
echo.
Pause
goto :eof

:Label 3
REM display that the file in the last check was found
echo found DirectoryNames.txt
REM for loop to filter through every line in a file
echo.
for /f %%i in (F:\file_sync_diff\FileNameList.txt) do call :Sub %%i
goto Label 4
goto :eof

:Label 4
REM thanks to Endoro@StackOverFlow
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
REM set associative arrays
set "tfileA=F:\file_sync_diff\FileNameList.txt"
set "tfileB=F:\file_sync_diff\DirectoryNames.txt"
REM setup for loops
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n $ "%tfileA%"') do set "$a%%a=%%b"&set /a countA=%%a
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n $ "%tfileB%"') do set "$b%%a=%%b"&set /a countB=%%a

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /l %%a in (1 1 %countA%) do (
    echo.
    move "!$a%%a!.txt" "!$b%%a!"
    echo.
    echo ^>"!$b%%a!\!$a%%a!" echo(!$c%%a!)
    echo.
endlocal

:Sub
echo Writing %1
REM copy the contents of FileDumpText.txt to the file that was passed in the last method
type F:\file_sync_diff\FileDumpText.txt >>  %1.txt
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion with `associative arrays`:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "tfileA=K:\file_sync_diff\FileNameList.txt"
set "tfileB=K:\file_sync_diff\DirectoryNames.txt"
set "tfileC=K:\file_sync_diff\FileDumpText.txt"

for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n $ "%tfileA%"') do set "$a%%a=%%b"&set /a countA=%%a
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n $ "%tfileB%"') do set "$b%%a=%%b"&set /a countB=%%a
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n $ "%tfileC%"') do set "$c%%a=%%b"&set /a countC=%%a
if "%countA%"=="%countB%" (echo %countA% line(s^) found in %tfileA% and %tfileB%.) else echo Line mismatch: %tfileA%:%countA% - %tfileB%:%countB%&goto:eof
if "%countA%"=="%countC%" (echo %countA% line(s^) found in %tfileC%.) else echo Line mismatch: %tfileA%:%countA% - %tfileC%:%countC%&goto:eof

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /l %%a in (1 1 %countA%) do (
    echo copy "!$a%%a!" "!$b%%a!"
    echo ^>"!$b%%a!\!$a%%a!" echo(!$c%%a!
)
endlocal
```

---

output is:

```
3 line(s) found in K:\file_sync_diff\FileNameList.txt and K:\file_sync_diff\DirectoryNames.txt.
3 line(s) found in K:\file_sync_diff\FileDumpText.txt.
copy "red" "K:\file_sync_diff\cat"
>"K:\file_sync_diff\cat\red" echo(more text 1
copy "orange" "K:\file_sync_diff\dog"
>"K:\file_sync_diff\dog\orange" echo(more text 2
copy "purple" "K:\file_sync_diff\333"
>"K:\file_sync_diff\333\purple" echo(more text 3
```